# Reactjs ES6 syntax error on my code snippet

Tags: reactjs

New to reactjs here. In the working [code snippet](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/ZXeOBm?editors=0010), when I make change the function `handleChange` to make it ES6 style (in order to avoid the `bind(this)`), it gives error on the `=` after `handleChange`. Wonder why.

=== the code with my change ==

```
function BoilingVerdict(props) {
  if (props.celsius >= 100) {
    return <p>The water would boil.</p>;
  }
  return <p>The water would not boil.</p>;
}

class Calculator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {temperature: ''};
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({temperature: e.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    const temperature = this.state.temperature;
    return (
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Enter temperature in Celsius:</legend>
        <input
          value={temperature}
          onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <BoilingVerdict
          celsius={parseFloat(temperature)} />
      </fieldset>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Calculator />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: what error do you get? I believe that semicolon is missing after the assignment.

Comment: Thank you @Sulthan, that's exactly the cause of the error. I have got used to not having a `;` in JS since it's not always necessary.  If you write up a line answer, I will accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon after the assignment:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({temperature: e.target.value});
};
```

The error ("Unexpected token") is probably just an editor error. It does not affect functionality because the semicolon should be inserted automatically.

[image]

Comment: In JavaScript semicolons are optional.

Comment: @Cristy Nope. In JS semicolons are inserted automatically. That's not the same.

Comment: But then what's the difference if he adds it or not? The parser will add it anyway, isn't that just a linting error?

Comment: wtf
Its not about syntax its about class properties.
whats wrong with author set this answer as accpted

Comment: @DmitriyKovalenko The problem is that the question is unclear about the error. That's why I posted this as a comment originally. If the OP considers this the answer, then I am more than happy to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse your code with babel to es2015. Because your statement is a class property you should have [transform-class-properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) plugin (its a part of es2015 preset)